# Can the webkit-speech-recognition API be used with the audio output from a webpage?

Tags: speech-recognition, html5-audio

Most examples I've seen use the browser's microphone as the input source for the speech recognition capabilities in HTML 5.  Is there any way to specify the source, or change it to the audio output from the webpage?  Perhaps using something like this [library](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) or a raw audio file?

Answer (score 2):

In general, you cannot do it as the [API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html) doesn't let the user to specify the speech source. A limited workaround could be redirecting the target machine's audio output to the microphone input.